# correct way to read properties file

Tags: java, properties-file

I am having trouble finding out the right way to load a properties file.
The structure is : Inside `src/com.training` , I have my class and the properties file as well. I have to read it using the absolute path as shown in the code below to get it to work:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;
input = new FileInputStream("D:/Dev/workspace/Training/src/com/training/consolemessages.properties");                 
prop.load(input);
System.out.print(prop.getProperty("INITIAL_MESSAGE"));
```

How can I use the relative path to work in this code for accessing the properties file. The properties file and the class which is accessing are both at the same level '/src/com.training'

Comment: The class is in the `src` directory? It's usually in the `classes` directory by the time you run it.

Comment: I meant the .java file

Comment: Well, the class loader searches relative to the *class* file, not the source file. You should make sure that you have the resource folder under your classes hierarchy rather than the src.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put your properties files into `src/resources` folder, and fetch them on classpath.

You could do something like this:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/consolemessages");

System.out.println(bundle.getString("INITIAL_MESSAGE"));
```

When using `ResourceBundle`, `Locale` support is also easy to implement, should you need to have language specific properties.

Comment: Thanks. Worked beautifully.

Comment: Just curious: What should I consider before deciding whether I should : 1. Read properties file using the util.properties  OR 2. Read properties files using the ResourceBundle

Comment: I know with the `ResourceBundle.getBundle()` caches automatically, so the file is only read once. I don't know what the deal is with the `Properties.class` but with the code from your example, the .properties file will be read (from the disk) on every initialize, unless you make sure you are able to access the `Properties.class` statically, or by instantiating is as a singleton